# Javascript Print method works in jsfiddle but not in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to run the function below in my asp.net page using IE-11:

```
  function openWin()
  {
    var myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");

    myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.focus();
    print(myWindow);
    myWindow.close();

  }
```

This runs very well on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/1674/) using internet explorer. 
However, when I run my asp.net web application in internet explorer, this function causes the internet explorer to stop working and all the windows close.

This is my aspx page source:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PrintBarcode.aspx.cs" Inherits="Application.Barcode.PrintBarcode" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .titlelabel {
            font-size: large;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        html {
            background-color: rgb(244,244,244);
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function openWin() {

            var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
            myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");

            myWindow.document.close();
            myWindow.focus();
            print(myWindow);
            myWindow.close();

        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>

                        <td>

                            <asp:Label ID="lblBarcode" runat="server" Text=" Barcode" CssClass="titlelabel"></asp:Label>

                        </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <div id="test">
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgbarcode" Width="80px" />
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="align-items: center; text-align: center" colspan="3">
                        <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="openWin()" />
                        <%--<asp:Button ID="BtnPrint" runat="server" OnClientClick="openWin()" Text="Print" />--%>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

I got a small update which i'm not sure if it can help. After clicking on the print button and getting that exception that Internet Explorer has stopped working, I got a window to Debug and Cancel. When I chose debug I was moved to the Visual Studio solution again and although I couldn't see any useful information but when I pressed "Continue", the page actually showed the print dialogue. But without "debugging" and "continuing", IE crashes completely.

Comment: tried the exact same code with my IE11 and it's perfectly working fine. The modal window shows up and closes and then the Print dialog appears. Seems like an isolated browser issue for you. Can you try resetting IE? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/reset-ie-settings#ie=ie-11-win-7

Comment: @Roman Thanks a lot for your reply. Have you tried it from a Visual studio web application project ? I just created a new project, added this code to default.aspx and it produces the same error for IE 11. I also tried resetting explorer setting and restarted but still the same error.

Comment: It may not be the cause here, but remember that many server languages tend to leave spaces before `<!DOCTYPE html>` and IE changes its rendering mode if the doctype isn't the first string it encounters on the HTML page. Check if the rendering engine is the same on your ASP page and on the fiddle.

Comment: @user3340627 yes, I forgot to mentioned that I did it on VS 2013

Comment: @saeraphin From Developer Tools, I opened the DOM Explorer for the asp page and at the very top I can see <!DOCTYPE html>  so this means it's rendered correctly, right ?

Comment: @user3340627 you should rather use the "view page source" function and make sure that the doctype tag is the first character of your page (no spaces or line breaks before).